# How to find the correct amount of combinations

Tags: java, eclipse, algorithm, combinations

So recently, I was given this problem in my programming course:

A useful technique for catching typing errors is to use a check digit. For example, suppose that a school assigns a
six-digit number to each student. A seventh digit can be determined from the other digits with the use of the following formula:

> 7<sup>th</sup> digit = (1 * (1<sup>st</sup> digit) + 2 * (2<sup>nd</sup> digit) + . . . + 6 * (6<sup>th</sup> digit)) % 10

When a user types in a student number, the user types all seven digits. If the number is typed incorrectly, the check
digit will fail to match in 90% of the cases. Write an interactive program that prompts for a six-digit student number
and reports the check digit for that number, using the preceding formula.

Once you correctly complete this program, answer the following:

How many total valid student numbers can be generated that are 7 digits long? Modify your program to answer this question

-
I've already done the first half of this problem, where I need to write the program that generates the code but i need help with the second half, namely: How do I find the total number of valid student numbers that can be made with 7 digits?  I mean, the parameters of this second half are really vague and I feel like it's some kind of trick question. is there some kind of formula I'm not aware of that could solve this? Any advice at all is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Trivial: `10^6`, since you can assign the first six digits freely, the last is completely constrained. But this should be moved to Math.SE.

Comment: Hmmm is 0000000 a valid number in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Just think about implementing it:

You can loop through numbers 100 000 to 999 999 that are all 6 digit numbers. You can compute 7-th digit from the first 6 digits. This number will be a good number because it has 7 digits and the 7-th digit matches the constraint. And there are no other good numbers because you looked at all possibilities for first 6 digits of the potencial good number.

So the total count of good numbers is 999 999 - 100 000 + 1 = **900 000**.
Or 999 999 - 0 + 1 = 1 000 000, if 0000000 is considered a valid number.

Comment: 0000000<sub>8<\sub> ~= 0<sub>10<\sub>